# Execute base component before using route component for auth

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a small sample application that loads various components based on routes in Angular 2 (using TypeScript).

What I'd like to try next is a way to do is auth checking before the the actual component that belongs to a route is called.

I could for example easily create some sort of a base class and let all of my component classes extend from that. But then I have to make sure all of my components call the constructor of the base class.

But perhaps there is a more "Angular 2" way to achieve the same goal?

I haven't really found much info on this matter yet. Is there a way to trigger, let's say an `AuthComponent` class before any other component is loaded?

Answer (score 1):

Check the `@CanActivate` annotation:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/CanActivate-decorator.html

you can prevent the component from getting instantiated and reroute them to login.

Comment: But this doesn't allow me to redirect a user to the Login page. As far as I can tell this only prevents the component from being loaded.

Comment: what prevents you from redirecting?

Comment: The  `CanActivate` function expects a `bool` as a return value. I can't do anything else in there. There is also no way to inject the `Router` class in it which I also need to do a redirect.

Comment: `window.location = '/login'` or `window.location = '#login'; return false;`

Comment: If you want to use the router object you have to instantiate the component in order to inject it, you can do so by using `OnActivate` instead, implementing the `routerOnActivate` method, but that would make little sense, why would you want to activate the component if you are going to redirect them out anyway? maybe you can do this if you implement a middle man empty routing object whose whole job is to implement this method and his route would be something like `'/...'`. See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/OnActivate-interface.html .